# Morningstar vs. Damage Reduction/Bludgeoning

Tags: pathfinder-1e, damage-resistance, damage-types

Exactly as the name says, how does the morningstar work against say a skeleton which has DR 5/bludgeoning, since a morningstar is both bludgeoning AND piercing?  I have looked online, and found some that say the DR applies because part is piercing, but I have also found some that say because the skeleton does not have DR against BOTH bludgeoning AND piercing, the DR doesn't apply.  Really need to get this clarified, as I am about to literally take on endless waves of the undead.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**The morningstar will bypass their damage reduction.**

From the [PFSRD](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons) on Weapon Qualities (*emphasis mine*):

> **Type:** Weapons are classified according to the type of damage they deal: B for bludgeoning, P for piercing, or S for slashing. Some monsters may be resistant or immune to attacks from certain types of weapons. Some weapons deal damage of multiple types. If a weapon causes two types of damage, the type it deals is not half one type and half another; all damage caused is of both types. *Therefore, a creature would have to be immune to both types of damage to ignore any of the damage caused by such a weapon.*

The [morningstar](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons/weapon-descriptions/morningstar) deals both bludgeoning *and* piercing damage, and so bypasses DR/bludgeoning.

Comment: Thank you. I have found people quoting that, but also others quoting that any penalty applies to the whole, so thank you again for the clarification.

Comment: @Pethrax **If** you were taking a penalty it would apply to the whole. The emphasized section above says you *don't* take a penalty.